# copying char to char array reverse

Tags: java

```
public class palindrome {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
     String name="caac";
     char com[]=name.toCharArray();

     char[] con=new char[4];
     for(int i=0,j=3;i<com.length;i++,j--)
     {

         com[j]=con[i];
         System.out.println(i+" "+j+"value of i "+con[i]);

     }

   }
}
```

i want to copy char com to char c in reverse, i got blank output, whats wrong with this program.what correction should i made.this question body does not meet our quality that line i dont want to see stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

small correction to existing code on the line

```
 con[j] = com[i];
```

and

```
 System.out.println(i + " " + j + "value of i " + com[i] +" "+con[j]);
```

works well.

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {
        String name = "daac";
        char com[] = name.toCharArray();

        char[] con = new char[4];
        for (int i = 0, j = 3; i < com.length; i++, j--) {
            con[j] = com[i];
            System.out.println(i + " " + j + "value of i " + com[i] +" "+con[j]);

        }

    }
```

Other solution is to use `StringBuffer.reverse` for the string

```
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(name);
  char reverse[] = sb.reverse().toString().toCharArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like com, con and i and j are mixed up. I'd highly recommend avoiding i and j together, even if textbooks do it. Use i and k instead, or better still something that is representive of what the variable purpose, also com and con confusingly similar.

If you change to this:

```
con[j] = com[i];
System.out.println(i + " " + j + " value of i " + com[i] + " " + con[j]);
```

Shows this output, is this what you expected?

```
0 3 value of i c c
1 2 value of i a a
2 1 value of i a a
3 0 value of i c c
```

There is no harm or performance hit in using longer more descriptive variables, this makes it more obvious where problems are. e.g.

```
char original[] = name.toCharArray();

char[] reversed = new char[4];
for (int forwards = 0, backwards = 3; forwards < original.length; forwards++, backwards--) {

    reversed[backwards] = original[forwards];
    System.out.println(
            forwards + " " + backwards + " value of i " + original[forwards] + " " + reversed[backwards]);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you could make your much smaller then what you want.If you want to reverse the char[] which is created from a string you could first reverse the string and then you could create  the array.

```
String name="caac";
String reverse= new StringBuffer(name).reverse().toString();
  char com[]=name.toCharArray();//which contains reversed array
```

Answer (score 0):

One more method to reverse char array:

```
public char[] reverseArray(char[] source) {
    char[] reversed = new char[source.length];
    IntStream.range(0, source.length).forEach(i -> reversed[source.length - 1 -i] = source[i]);
    return reversed;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Simon Asir.
I recommend you write a function, an example is given below demonstrate it, i didn't understand what problem(task) you are solving:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String name="something eatable";
    char com[]=name.toCharArray();
    char[] reversed = reverseArray(com);
      for (char c:reversed)
          System.out.print(c+" ");
    System.out.println(isPalindrome(new char[]{'b','a'}));
    System.out.println(isPalindrome(new char[]{'a','b','a'}));
}
public static char[] reverseArray(char[] arr){
    char[] reversed = new char[arr.length];
    for (int i=0, j=arr.length-1; i < arr.length; i++, j--){
        reversed[i]=arr[j];
    }
    return reversed;
}
public static boolean isPalindrome(char[] arr){
    for (int head=0, tail=arr.length-1; head<=tail; head++, tail--){
        if (arr[head]!=arr[tail])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```